Add new module in Compose Multi Platform (CMP)
Currently, I working in the Compose Multiplatform and want to add "Kotlin Multiplatform Shared Module". The name of module is ":feature:learning", I already add dependency to composeApp module. here the screen capture:

I create composable function at the learning module, the file is LearningScreen.kt
But after add the dependency, still can't linking to the new module.

Thank you
